# Copying files using call to system()

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a function that calls the Intel portability function 'system':

```
subroutine system_subr(JobString,ExitStatus)
    implicit none

    character(len=*),intent(in) :: JobString
    integer,intent(out) :: ExitStatus

    integer shiftr,system

    ExitStatus=system(JobString)
end subroutine system_subr
```

My program is doing something like the following:

```
call system_subr('mv myfile newfilename', status)
call system_subr(submitjobstring, status)
```

The copy command in the second call is done over ssh - an example submitjobstring (parent job is running in /sharedscratch/user/test) would be:

```
ssh node1 " mkdir -p /scratch/user/9570.0.70468 ; cd /sharedscratch/user/test/ ; cp -r newfilename otherfile /scratch/user/9570.0.70468 ;
```

This code has been working without problems for a number of years. However, on our new compute cluster this is working most of the time, but occasionally I am running into problems.

The error I sometimes get is:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘newfilename’: No such file or directory
```

If I go and look in /scratch/user/9570.0.70468/, otherfile (created before the start of the program) has been copied there, but newfilename has not. I also find that newfilename does actually exist in /sharedscratch/user/test. If I check the exit status on the first call of the pair to system_subr, it is always 0.

If I put a sleep command between the two calls to system_subr, it seems to always work fine. Does the system function not wait for the mv command to complete before continuing? I would really like to understand why this happens.

Comment: Please show the exact code and the error messages. How do you call system_subr? What is the value of Jobstring? Do you check the ExitStatus?

Comment: What is the filesystem is being used?

Comment: I have added more detail for clarity, though the exact code is far too long to paste here. Thanks.

Comment: Try to make a minimal fully compilable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Does it still happen when you make a short program that does just the renaming and copying? What kind of filesystem do you use?

Comment: `system` indeed waits for `mv` to return.  I'm guessing you have a network latency issue that is letting `mv` think its finished a milisecond too soon.  You should add linux,ssh,etc tags see if anyone knows the best way to reliably ensure the `mv` is really completed.

Comment: I think the same, but at least the information about the (network-)filesystem would be useful.

Comment: Also we now have a standardized method to access the command line by the execute_command_line routine: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/526163 which takes also a wait parameter, so you can explicitly state wether you want to wait or not. Though I'd guess this will not help as already pointed out by agentp. You could poll with inquire for the existence of the file to be on the save side.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Sorry for going cold on this topic for a bit. Had a bit of lightbulb moment when you asked about the filesystem. The place I am copying the files from is NFS-mounted on both nodes, so although the mv command completed on one node, there is a delay before this change is visible on the other node. Our older cluster used NFS3 rather than NFS4, which must have done the caching differently somehow. I've fixed the problem by using scp instead. Interesting to learn about execute_command_line, but I think it only works with the newest Intel compilers.